# Heroku showing "blank app" even though Procfile is running

Tags: git, heroku

Any single path I visit all I see is the Heroku welcome page, which according to [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/68) sends over a 502 status code.

also according to this [heroku HTTP routing guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing) it also sends the 502 if there are invalid responses sent by the app. I recently deployed another app built on the same boiler, and there's not much that's dramatically different about this one.

I suppose the two things I can think of are that this app uses `open-uri` accepting user input, and that it sends (sanitized) html in responses. But I'm not aware of restictions for this on Heroku, and I can SSH in and `open("http://google.com").read` fine.

Here is my procfile:

```
web: env RACK_ENV=production bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
```

And my `config.ru`:

```
require './server.rb'
run Server
```

On localhost, I use `bundle exec thin start` and everything works fine.

I see this output for `heroku ps`:

```
=== web (Free): env RACK_ENV=production bundle exec thin start -p $PORT (1)
web.1: up 2017/03/16 17:53:44 -0700 (~ 19m ago)
```

I also SSH in to check that the app can run and the database is set up:

```
heroku run "irb -r ./server.rb"
Running irb -r ./server.rb on ⬢ music-sharing... up, run.2985 (Free)
irb(main):001:0> Audio.count
=> 0
```

In `heroku logs --tail` I see this kind of thing after making a request:

> 2017-03-17T01:45:44.022727+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=music-sharing.herokuapp.com request_id=2e41fca8-0913-4a09-8635-2a26586c3234 fwd="73.170.238.232" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https

I also made sure the app is at the root dir:

```
heroku run bash
Running bash on ⬢ music-sharing... up, run.5955 (Free)
~ $ ls
bin        db_config.rb  Procfile    server.rb
config.ru      Gemfile   Rakefile    tmp
crud_generator.rb  Gemfile.lock  README.md   vendor
db         models.rb     server_push.rb  ws.rb
~ $
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer depends on something I didn't include in the question so it's a little unfair, but anywhere here was the problem:

I was deploying using this script:

```
git subtree push --prefix server heroku master
```

That's because my repo has `server/` and `client/` folders (two separate apps)

For some reason this didn't work.

I went into the `server/` folder, made a new (temporary, deploy-only) git repo in there, committed everything, pointed it to the heroku remote, and force pushed.

If I figure out more info on why the `--prefix` push wasn't working (it was working on my other app), I will add it here.

---

Update

got the script working by modifying to this:

```
git push heroku `git subtree split --prefix server master`:master --force
```

Comment: Im having a similar issue, but im not using any specific git commands to only push my client, im pushing both apps at once, and while it was working. before, now in this deploy the screen is just blank, but i do think it has to do with git somehow

Comment: @xunux I wish I could help you but this was so long ago I forgot all context. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the `H81 - Blank app` issue. you have to push the code to `main` or `master` branch

e.g. `git push heroku HEAD:master`

if you use simple `git push heroku` it will create the branch name same as in you local repo.

use this command `git remote show heroku` to view branches in heroku server